# SVN in Adobe Brackets

Tags: svn, adobe-brackets

I did a search in the extension manager and a quick Google search which didn't get very far. Figured I'd give Stack a shot. Does anyone know of an extension/plug-in for the Brackets IDE that integrates svn? Or is my only bet to just use the command line to update files?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like people are working on it, but there's nothing ready yet as far as an extension. I'd keep an eye on this repo:
https://github.com/krewenki/brackets-svn

Comment: This project is dead... see this: https://github.com/krewenki/brackets-svn/issues/3